# Re-ordering fields in an Attribute table in ArcGIS Online

Tags: attribute-table, arcgis-online, fields-attributes

Im trying to rearrange the order of the fields in an attribute table layer in ArcGIS Online.

Ive read that i must hold down the left key and drag the field header left or right. I tried but that didnt work.

Does this work for anyone?
Can someone help me.

Comment: You read wrong doc. Click customise pop-up, you all see arrows on the right. Select field and use arrow

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on FelixIP comment, the ordering of your fields in the attribute table is determined by the order set out in the pop up configuration.

[image]